# Multiply keys with the same value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this object:

```
obj = {1: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2};
```

How can I find and multiply only the keys with value 2 on other independent variables ?
I want to compare in this case 1*2 with 5*2.

```
var1 = 1*2;
var2 = 5*2;
```

Thank you!

Comment: this question has nothing to do with angular/typescript based on current content

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share some code.

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {1: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2};
const arr = Object.keys(obj).reduce((sum, key) => {
  if(obj[key] === 2) sum.push(Number(key) * 2) ;
  return sum;
}, []);
console.log(arr);
```

Then `arr` is what you want (`[2, 10]`)

Comment: Thank you. Why I receive this error: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
?

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over your object with `Object.entries` and `Array.prototype.reduce`.

`Object.entries` returns an array of key/value pairs:

```
Object.entries({1: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2});
//=> [["1",2],["4",1],["5",2]]
```

With `Array.prototype.reduce` you can return an array of products of key/value pairs for which value is equal to `2`:

```
Object.entries({1: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2}).reduce((acc, [k, v]) =>
    v === 2 ? acc.concat(k * v) : acc, []);
```

Now let's create a function that accepts 1) a value to look for and 2) a key/value pairs object:

```js
const multKeys = (value, obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) =>
    v === value ? acc.concat(k * v) : acc, []);
    
    
console.log(multKeys(2, {1: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2}));
```

Then you can assign each product to variables via [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
var [var1, var2] = multKeys(2, {1: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2});
var1; //=> 2
var2; //=> 10
```

Answer (score -1):

It's easy, even if I don't really get the point of why would you do something like this..

```js
obj = {1: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
  if(k == 2 || obj[k] == 2) console.log(k * obj[k]); 
})
```

Comment: it's about a game with five dice. And if I have two pairs I want to compare them so I can extract the biggest one.

Comment: I received two errors with your code: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.
and The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
But thank you anyway :)

Comment: I guess you have tested it with something else then since as you can se by pressing "Run Code Snippet" it works :)))

Comment: Yes, indeed. With WebStorm.. Why I receive this errors ?

Comment: What have you passed to this function?